# MongoDB : Is there a way to detect a value trend using aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to detect the "trend" of a value in a collection.

Let's say I have the following:

```
{ created_at: 2014-12-01, value:1015 }
{ created_at: 2014-12-01, value:1015 }
{ created_at: 2014-12-01, value:1019 }
{ created_at: 2014-12-02, value:1018 }
{ created_at: 2014-12-02, value:1021 }
{ created_at: 2014-12-03, value:1010 }
{ created_at: 2014-12-03, value:1012 }
{ created_at: 2014-12-03, value:1011 }
{ created_at: 2014-12-04, value:1012 }
```

I just want to have an output like:

```
{ created_at: 2014-12-01, average: 1016, diff: 0}
{ created_at: 2014-12-02, average: 1019, diff: 3}
```

With diff being the difference of the average value between
the two dates.

I figured out how to calculate the averages, find min/max and first/last values in the collection, but can't find a way to compare the two averages...

Comment: Calculating the average difference would be better if done in the application code. Currently it may not be possible using the aggregation framework.

Comment: You can't realistically compute output like that with the aggregation framework (one or several pipelines), but there is a lot you can calculate instead. I think more explanation of how and why you are detecting trends would be the best way to help us give good advice.

Comment: @wdberkeley I have a collection that holds readings from a network of sensors (named "sensor_readings"). The readings come in random time and stored just the way you see in the example - just add a full timestamp. Every 10 minutes I want to aggregate the data, group them every minute, calculated the minute average and the difference from the previous minute.

Answer (score 1):

Rough outline: I would calculate the average for the ten minute period:

```
> var avgCursor = db.sensor_readings.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "created_at" : { "$gt" : ten_minutes_ago, "$lte" : now } } }
    { "$group" : { "_id" : 0, "average" : { "$avg" : "$value" } } }
]}
> var avgDoc = avgCursor.toArray()[0]
> avgDoc
{ "_id" : 0, "average" : 23 }
```

Then I would store it in another collection:

```
> db.sensor_averages.insert({ "start" : ten_minutes_ago, "end" : now, "average" : avgDoc.average })
```

Finally, recall the two averages you need to compute the difference, and compute it:

```
> var diffCursor = db.sensor_averages.find({ "start" : { "$gte" : twenty_minutes_ago } }).sort({ "start" : -1 })
> var diffArray = diffCursor.toArray()
> var difference = diffArray[0].average - diffArray[1].average
```

You could also skip the periodic aggregations and instead keep a running average updated in `sensor_averages`, jumping to a new doc every 10 minutes. At the beginning of each 10 minute period, insert into `sensor_averages` a doc

```
{
    "start" : now,
    "svalues" : 0,
    "nvalues" : 0
}
```

then on each insert of a `sensor_reading` document for the next ten minutes, also update the `sensor_averages` doc:

```
db.sensor_averages.update(
    { "start" : now_rounded_to_the_ten_minute_boundary },
    { "$inc" : { "svalues" : value, "nvalues" : 1 } }
)
```

Then, when you want the difference between averages, recall the appropriate two docs, divide `svalues` by `nvalues` to get the average, and subtract.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming these are actual dates according to your comments on "aggregate per minute" the only real way to do this in a single pass is using mapReduce. The key here is that mapReduce can store a global variable and therefore "track" your last result in order to determine the "difference" between each aggregated record

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        // Round date to the minute
        var key = this.created_at.valueOf()
            - ( this.created_at.valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 ) );
        emit( key, { "average": this.value } );
    },
    function(key,values) {
        values = values.map(function(i) { return i.average });
        var result = {
           "average": Math.floor(Array.avg(values))
        };
        return result;
    },
    {
        "out": { "inline": 1 },
        "scope": { "lastAvg": 0 },
        "finalize": function(key,value) {
            value.diff = ( lastAvg == 0 ) ? 0 : value.average - lastAvg;
            lastAvg = value.average;
            return value;
        }
    }
)
```

Alternately you can "post-process" as has been mentioned and do the same thing in your client code to calculate the difference as you iterate the cursor with a similar scoped variable. As a shell example:

```js
var lastAvg = 0;
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "$subtract": [
            { "$subtract": [ "$created_date", new Date(0) ] },
            { "$mod": [
                { "$subtract": [ "$created_date", new Date(0) ] },
                1000 * 60
            ]}
        ]},
        "average": { "$avg": "$value" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.average = Math.floor(doc.average);
    doc.diff = ( lastAvg == 0 ) ? 0 : doc.average - lastAvg;
    lastAvg = doc.average;
    printjson(doc);
})
```

In both cases there I am using the date math principles in order to convert the date object into a unix/epoch timestamp representation as a number which is rounded out to it's nearest floor by minute. With the aggregation framework you could alternately use the [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) to extract the date parts for grouping.

In either case it's really simple to re-cast that as a `Date` object where required either internally with `.mapReduce()` or in post processing using `.aggregate()`.

So in wrap up, you can either use the "global scope" functionality of mapReduce or you can just process the resulting cursor from aggregate in order to work out the differences between each grouping in results.

Comment: Neil, can you show how to do this spring-data-mongodb?