# Why does .aggregate() return keys in reverse order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This has been bugging me for some time now. The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) for MongoDB is a great tool and generally more appropriate case for usage than [`.mapReduce()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) for most cases unless the latter is actually more suited.

It does of course actually perform it's operations using methods implemented in the native C++ compilation as compared to JavaScript interpretation and is therefore "faster" in most cases than the mapReduce alternative.

But the main issue here is "What gives with the 'reversed' key order in results?". This has at least been the case over the last few major releases if it was not always the case ( not really testing every release here, just 2.6.x and 3.x candidates as of writing ). But it's always in "reverse" and this seems really counter intuitive as I will give in an example.

Consider the basic collection as a trivial example:

```js
db.example.insert([
    { "field": "A", "value": 1 },
    { "field": "A", "value": 2 },
    { "field": "B", "value": 3 },
    { "field": "B", "value": 4 },
    { "field": "C", "value": 5 },
    { "field": "C", "value": 6 }
])
```

Once that collection is in place, when you want to run a sample aggregation operation like this:

```js
db.example.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$field",
        "value": { "$sum": "$value" }
    }}
])
```

Then the returned results will always return mysteriously like this:

```js
[
    { "_id" : "C", "value" : 11 },
    { "_id" : "B", "value" : 7 },
    { "_id" : "A", "value" : 3 }
]
```

That will always be consistent, and no matter what the order of insertion of the actual documents is the keys will "always" be produced in "reverse order".

Now on the other hand let's consider what `.mapReduce()` does. And I'm not going to quote directly a piece of documentation but "sic editorial":

> MapReduce will always order the keys emitted before processing to the "reduce" function as a general optimisation.

Or basically something like that is said. So the following code:

```js
db.example.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit( this.field, this.value );
    },
    function(key,values) {
        return Array.sum( values );
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Produces this kind of result, and in line with the general premise of the documented behavior:

```js
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : "A",
            "value" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : "B",
            "value" : 7
        },
        {
            "_id" : "C",
            "value" : 11
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 231,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 6,
        "emit" : 6,
        "reduce" : 3,
        "output" : 3
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Now, that is of course ordered with the natural "ascending" order of the grouping key as specified and in exactly the way that is reasonably documented. Moreover, considering how most SQL storage engines handle this sort of aggregation work in results, then it just "makes sense" to return in an ordered key fashion.

So really, "What is the problem here?". As a frequent contributer to answering many of the community questions I "can say" and with a respectable amount of authority that the general expectancy is that the results **should** be ordered by the "grouping key" as people do reasonably expect. Furthermore there are also common use cases that want to further "analyse" the aggregation results in "series" as they **should** naturally occur. A common case is "analysing the difference between each aggregation result" such as ["determining the difference between each average on days"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28823638/2313887). Just an example, but similar things get asked often enough.

Most of us (and at least those with some experience ) are well aware of the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) aggregation pipeline stage. But I think in the spirit of what is really being asked here is "Why should we have to do that?".

The original aggregation option via `.mapReduce()` just does it like people would expect. So why does `.aggregate()` just not do it the same way?

Is there a [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) on this? Is there real action to do something about it?

The current workaround of applying `$sort` as an additional stage is really very "crufty" and I think the community using the product deserves a lot better than that. The expected behavior of any "aggregation" operation is that the "keys" should be ordered in the results. So why can we not do so and what is currently being done to fix this?

It's a real shame if there is not an immediate effort because this cripples an otherwise "very useful tool" that people should flock to when considering MongoDB as a storage solution for their application.

I would like to hope we can work towards something better.

---

For just a little more clarification. It is noted that the aggregate output is not specifically ordered but it does actually appear in "discovery order" of the keys, but of course in reverse. So an example like:

```js
db.example.insert([
    { "field": "B", "value": 4 },
    { "field": "A", "value": 1 },
    { "field": "B", "value": 3 },
    { "field": "C", "value": 5 },
    { "field": "A", "value": 2 },
    { "field": "C", "value": 6 }
])
```

Would produce:

```js
{ "_id" : "C", "value" : 11 }
{ "_id" : "A", "value" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "B", "value" : 7 }
```

So the stack is always reversed by the order in which the grouping keys were discovered.

That's the question, that the stack is always reversed along with why the different approach to what mapReduce does in presorting the grouping key. Is there any benefit or specific reason? Or can it be done better.

Answer (score 7):

I really don't think MongoDB there should be ordering the result by default. If you need documents to be in a certain order then you should always sort them.

> The original aggregation option via .mapReduce() just does it like people would expect

I'm not sure people expect this - I certainly don't expect things to be in a certain order unless I specifically request it. If they happen to be in some kind of order then it is an implementation detail and you generally shouldn't rely on it.

Open a Jira bug about it if you think it would be useful, but I personally don't see the need. If a user can write a `$group` then they will also be able to figure out `$sort`.

Comment: Part of the question here does raise if a JIRA has even been considered and surely there should be one. Also you seem to be basically arguing that this is an "opinion" but your counterpoint is essentially an opinion in itself. So there really isn't any attempt made here to answer the essential question of why is there a difference between the two aggregation methods here or to what end there should be a difference. That is the question and an answer would address that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same inserts as yours and got the same result like yours on MongoDB version 3.4.4! Got interested and tried some more as explained below,

```
db.example.insert([
    { "field" : "A", "value" : 1 },
    { "field" : "B", "value" : 2 },
    { "field" : "C", "value" : 3 },
    { "field" : "D", "value" : 4 },
    { "field" : "E", "value" : 5 },
    { "field" : "A", "value" : 6 },
    { "field" : "B", "value" : 7 },
    { "field" : "C", "value" : 8 },
    { "field" : "D", "value" : 9 },
    { "field" : "E", "value" : 10 },
])
```

Once the collection was in place, ran the same aggregation operation like this:

```
db.example.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$field",
        "value": { "$sum": "$value" }
    }}
])
```

It returned results like this:

```
[
    { "_id" : "E", "value" : 15 },
    { "_id" : "D", "value" : 13 },
    { "_id" : "C", "value" : 11 },
    { "_id" : "A", "value" : 7 },
    { "_id" : "B", "value" : 9 }
]
```

The aggregation output does not appear to have followed the order you mentioned, ie. reverse order of discovery. If it did then shouldn't the result of aggregation follow E,D,C,B,A rather than E,D,C,A,B?

These were removed and tried again with different documents

```
db.example.insert([
    { "field" : "A", "value" : 1 },
    { "field" : "B", "value" : 2 },
    { "field" : "C", "value" : 3 },
    { "field" : "D", "value" : 4 },
    { "field" : "E", "value" : 5 },
    { "field" : "E", "value" : 6 },
    { "field" : "D", "value" : 7 },
    { "field" : "C", "value" : 8 },
    { "field" : "B", "value" : 9 },
    { "field" : "A", "value" : 10 },
])
```

Ran the same aggregation operation like this:

```
db.example.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$field",
        "value": { "$sum": "$value" }
    }}
])
```

Returned results followed the same order as above, ie. E,D,C,A,B:

```
[
    { "_id" : "E", "value" : 11 },
    { "_id" : "D", "value" : 11 },
    { "_id" : "C", "value" : 11 },
    { "_id" : "A", "value" : 11 },
    { "_id" : "B", "value" : 11 }
]
```

Overall in the above scenarios there were no 'reversed' key order in results.