# How to get trends in spring-data-mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Referred to this link [MongoDB : Is there a way to detect a value trend using aggregation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335658/mongodb-is-there-a-way-to-detect-a-value-trend-using-aggregation) We are using spring-data-mongodb, and we want to calculate the trends and gross sales. We are turning up with 2 queries for getting trends and gross sales, is there any efficient way of doing the same? Please help.

Sample data :

```
 {"2000-01-01", 1000, "$"}
 {"2000-01-01", 1000, "$"}
 {"2000-01-01", 1000, "$"}
 {"2001-02-01", 2000, "$"}
 {"2001-02-01", 2000, "$"}
 {"2001-02-01", 2000, "$"}
 {"2002-03-01", 3000, "$"}
 {"2002-03-01", 3000, "$"}
 {"2002-03-01", 3000, "$"}
 {"2003-04-01", 4000, "$"}  
 {"2003-04-01", 4000, "$"} 
 {"2003-04-01", 4000, "$"}
```

For example we calculate gross sales for the period "2003-01-01" (Start date)  to "2004-01-01" (End Date) in a query and the result comes out to be:  $12000. 
The trends we calculate by another query "2002-01-01" (Start Date) to  "2003-01-01" (Start date of previous query),

```
    and the result comes out to be : $9000 ,
```

and

```
  subtract the previous result $12000 - $9000 (current result) = $3000 trends.
```

Is it possible to write a efficient single and efficient query for calculating gross sales and the gross trends  in spring-data-mongodb?
We tried the following :

```
   ** by concurrently running the two tasks (one of calculation gross sales and other of calculating trends) by threads and it seems forking thread from the java web application can be disastrous

 ** by using map reduce program in spring-data-mongodb, but of NO use, because we were unable to get the query for pre-dated date to run using map reduce.
```

Please help me know the other better alternatives to try for simultaneously executing calculating trends and gross sales using spring-data-mongodb. 
Regards
Kris